# Relativistic velocity addition from time dilation

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, inertial-frames

I'm trying to derive the relativistic velocity addition equation using the time dilation equations but I get a wrong result.
Assume the widely used scenario in which there are 3 clocks: O, A and B.
A is moving relative to O at velocity $v$.
B is moving relative to A at velocity $w$.
Find the velocity of B relative to O (in O's frame of reference).
The time dilation equations says:

$$t_A = t_O \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$$

$$t_B = t_A \sqrt{1-w^2/c^2}$$

$$t_B = t_O \sqrt{1-u^2/c^2}$$

From these 3 equations we want to derive $u$. Then we get:

$$t_O \sqrt{1-u^2/c^2} = t_O \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2} \sqrt{1-w^2/c^2}$$

$$1-u^2/c^2 = (1-v^2/c^2) (1-w^2/c^2)$$

$$1-u^2/c^2 = 1-v^2/c^2-w^2/c^2+v^2 w^2/c^4$$

$$u^2 = v^2 + w^2 - v^2 w^2/c^2$$

This is different from the equation

$$u = \frac{v + w}{1+v w/c^2}$$

Why doesn't the derivation of velocity using the time dilation equations alone work?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Note that we have an [equation editor built into the site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) which helps for readability of your post.

Comment: I think the problem here is remembering exactly what it meant by these time dilation equations. How about thinking about this little puzzler?: If a time $t_0$ goes by in O's frame then a time $t_A=t_0 \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ has gone by in A's frame, right? But from A's perspective when that same time $t_A$ has gone by on his clock, then according to his use of the time dilation equation a time $t_0=t_A \sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ should have gone by on O's clock. But then if you look at these equations and try to combine them, they're incompatible with each other for any v except v=0 ! What went wrong?

Comment: yes, they are incompatible, there should be asymetry in order for them to work; and actually the only case which i see for the equations to work, is when let's say observer A accelerated related to observer O and somehow his state changed; if both accelerates then equations are not working anymore

Answer (score 1):

The clocks on ships A and B are not just running slower compared to clock O. They are also offset from each other due to their different locations. If you look at the [Lorentz transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Coordinate_transformation) for the time coordinate
$$t' = \gamma\left(t - \frac{xv}{c^2}\right),$$
you can see that the distance between the clocks is also a factor in how much the clocks differ in their readings. Since clocks A and B are moving at difference speeds, they must be at different locations, so the difference in time is not just due to a different running speed, but a difference in starting time (when the clocks would read zero). This is related to the [relativity of simultaneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity).

In short, relativity means you can't treat space and time separately, as a change in motion through one affects your motion through the other.

Comment: Thanks, this means that I used incomplete equations, since they are valid only in the case the comparison of time is performed at the same location in space (x = 0)

Answer (score 1):

Your first derived equation implies that $\gamma_u=\gamma_v\gamma_w$, which is not correct (time-dilation factors are not multiplicative). Instead, the correct relation [dropping the $c$'s] is 
$$\gamma_u=\gamma_v\gamma_w(1+vw).$$
This is most easily seen using rapidities [Minkowski-angles] $\theta$, where $v=\tanh\theta$.
I will modify your notation for clarity.
$v=\tanh\theta_{AO}$ and $\gamma_v=\cosh\theta_{AO}$ (where $\theta_{AO}$ is the rapidity from $O$ to $A$).
$w=\tanh\theta_{BA}$  and $\gamma_w=\cosh\theta_{BA}$
$u=\tanh\theta_{BO}$ and $\gamma_u=\cosh\theta_{BO}$
Since rapidities add, we have $\theta_{BO}=\theta_{BA}+\theta_{AO}$.
Thus,
 $\begin{align}\gamma_u=\cosh\theta_{BO}&=\cosh(\theta_{BA}+\theta_{AO})\\
&=\cosh\theta_{BA}\cosh\theta_{AO}+\sinh\theta_{BA}\sinh\theta_{AO}\\
&=\cosh\theta_{BA}\cosh\theta_{AO}(1+\tanh\theta_{BA}\tanh\theta_{AO})\\
&=\gamma_w\gamma_v(1+wv)\\
\end{align}$

---

So, your first derived equation is incorrect. To see why that is, it would be good to draw a spacetime diagram. I'll draw one using rotated graph paper so that we can visualize the ticks along the segments.

[image: Velocity Composition on Rotated Graph Paper]

Your first time-dilation equation can be written as $t_O=t_A \gamma_v=t_A \cosh\theta_{AO}$,
 which says that
 
the **adjacent leg $t_O$ is equal to the hypotenuse $t_A$ times $\cosh\theta_{AO}$** in a Minkowski-right-triangle. 
Furthermore, the event at $t_O$ along O's worldline is what he says is "simultaneous with the distant event at $t_A$ along Alice's worldline"... so maybe call it $t_{OsimA}$].
 
Similarly,
the **adjacent leg $t_A$ is equal to the hypotenuse $t_B$ times $\cosh\theta_{BA}$**, and
the **adjacent leg $t_O$ is equal to the hypotenuse $t_B$ times $\cosh\theta_{BO}$**.
But, from the diagram, if the first two are true, **the last one can't be true** since the event at $t_O$ on O's worldline can't be simultaneous with both $t_A$ on A's worldline and $t_B$ on B's worldline. **Simultaneity isn't generally transitive.**

So, you need to do some work to get the correct third time-dilation equation. The spacetime diagram might help.

---

By the way, since the rapidities add, we have
$\begin{align}u=\tanh\theta_{BO}&=\tanh(\theta_{BA}+\theta_{AO})\\
&=\frac{\tanh\theta_{BA}+\tanh\theta_{AO}}{1+\tanh\theta_{BA}\tanh\theta_{AO}}\\
&=\frac{w+v}{1+wv}\\
\end{align}$
which is the velocity-composition formula you seek.
In the diagram shown, $v=(3/5)$, $w=(5/13)$, and $u=(16/20)=(4/5)$.

so, the time-dilation factors are [adjacent/hypotenuse]:
 
$\gamma_v=(10/8)=(5/4)$, $\gamma_w=(13/12)$, and $\gamma_u=(20/12)=(5/3)$.

You can verify the velocity composition formula:
$\begin{align}u&=\frac{w+v}{1+wv}\\
\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)&=\frac{\left(\frac{5}{13}\right)+\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)}{1+\left(\frac{5}{13}\right)\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)}\\
\end{align}$

and the time-dilation factor relation:
$\begin{align}\gamma_u&=\gamma_w\gamma_v(1+wv)\\
\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)&=\left(\frac{13}{12}\right)\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)\left(1+\left(\frac{5}{13}\right)\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)\right)
\end{align}$

---

In addition, a multiplicative relation does hold for the doppler factors $k_v=\sqrt{\frac{1+v}{1-v}}$, which is equal to the exponential function of the rapidity:
$\begin{align}k_u=\exp\theta_{BO}&=\exp(\theta_{BA}+\theta_{AO})\\
&=\exp\theta_{BA}\exp\theta_{AO}\\
&=k_w k_v\\
\end{align}$
you can express this in terms of the velocities... do some algebra and get the velocity-composition formula. One develops this formula using a light ray (as shown) and relating the elapsed times from the common meeting event. (This is in the spirit of the Bondi k-calculus.)

[image: Doppler factors on Rotated Graph Paper]

In terms of the velocities in the diagram,
the doppler factors are [reception-leg/emission-leg]:
 
$k_v=(8/4)=2$, $k_w=(12/8)=(3/2)$, and $k_u=(12/4)=(3)$.

You can verify the Doppler-factor relation:
$\begin{align}k_u&=k_w k_v\\
(3)&=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)(2)
\end{align}$